# Gender group of custom event in Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I've just added a firebase analytics custom event on the client-side as below:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("uid", uid);
// gender value would be either 1 or 0
params.putString("gender", gender);
MyApp.getInstance().getFirebaseAnalytics().logEvent("completed_profile", params);
```

I went to Firebase Analytics dashboard and found parameters seem to be not working?
[image]

Anyway I can set gender info properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the gender/age info. That information will be automatically collected from the user's google account with which he logged in to download your app from the play store.